# How can I use Hershey fonts in matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, seaborn

I've transitioned from IDL, Supermongo plotting packages to iPython's versatile options (Matplotlib and Seaborn). However, I am still partial to the typography in IDL and SM that use Hershey fonts extensively. They lend themselves really well to visualisations, being clutter free and well designed.

Here's a few examples of how Hershey fonts look:

http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/Using_Hershey_Vector_Fon.html

Is there a way to incorporate these with seaborn and matplotlib? Does it make sense to make them True Type fonts first and install them so they are available to the font picker within these packages?

Will that play well with the LaTeX typesetting thats already pretty finicky in iPython?

Comment: IPython (capital "I") uses mathjax to render math text in the notebook. matplotlib (and seaborn via matplotlib) can use latex natively: http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html?highlight=latex

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Thanks to this TTF translation of the Hershey font.

https://github.com/yangcht/Hershey_font_TTF

Just download this font and choose this font in the matplotlib.

Here is an example after using this font.

[image]